# What is the most common encoding of messages to polynomials?

Tags: ntru

How polynomial based encryption schemes such as NTRU encode messages in to polynomials? Is there a generic conversion?

Comment: My first guess would be using a random message and deriving a symmetric key from it by hashing (e.g. using HKDF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NTRUEncrypt, a raw message *m* of octet string of length *l* octets is encoded through the following steps:

1. Padded it with a random salt of *b* byte and a few extra information to form the actual octet string *M* that is to be encrypted.
2. This *M* byte string is then converted to a binary string *Mbin* using octect-string-to-binary-string-primitive (OS2BSP).
3. In NTRUEncrypt, the message is actually a ternary polynomial, so for every 3 bits in *Mbin*, use a binary to ternary mapping as follows to convert it into a ternary string *Mtrin*.

   - {0, 0, 0} -> {0, 0}
   - {0, 0, 1} -> {0, 1}
   - {0, 1, 0} -> {0, -1}
   - {0, 1, 1} -> {1, 0}
   - {1, 0, 0} -> {1, 1}
   - {1, 0, 1} -> {1, -1}
   - {1, 1, 0} -> {-1, 0}
   - {1, 1, 1} -> {-1, 1}
4. Finally the message polynomial *m(x)* is to take each element in *Mtrin* as the corresponding coefficient.

See section 8 for more details of conversion, and section 10.2.2 for encryption procedure. 
https://github.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/ntru-crypto/blob/master/doc/EESS1-v3.1.pdf